# Languages suited for development in slow-moving institutions

Tags: java, php, enterprise

I have a project which is in the R&D phase at a university institution.  If this was a start-up I would use some language which is fast to work with like PHP or Ruby.  Considering that speed is less of an issue in my current project and stability, support, quality, and sanity are more important, is PHP suitable here?  Or is Java still the language for such projects?

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: I wouldn't immediately think of PHP when the question is _stability, support, quality, and sanity_. Yes, it is possible to write secure and reliable programs in PHP, but so much of the language's history is pointed in the other direction. But without more details on what you're trying to do, it's hard to even suggest a language. (And more important than the language might be the _libraries_ -- do you need to integrate with OpenCV or GPGME or GMP or...?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wan't to move slowly and still use PHP, you can use Zend Framework or Symfony for example. It will help if you have never used them before.

For stability, support, quality, etc. you should have things like Unit-testing, Continuous Integration and a good framework (with a big community and support).

In the face of PHP, you have all of that (PHPUnit, phpUnderControl, Zend/Symfony as a great frameworks) so PHP is a very good choice, in fact a better choice than Java. (Java web servers are harder to maintain).

As a PHP developer, that's my opinion.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about Ruby, but I have a background in PHP and some in Java, and recently discovered Python. Imho Python and [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) framework definitely deserve consideration.
Here is why:

- the code is clear, very [DRY](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself), and can be quite self-explanatory
- Djagno has a not-too-steep learning curve
- documantation is good, community is alive
- there are solutions for many situations already availible (my latest prob: trees in sql - [django-mptt](http://django-mptt.github.com/django-mptt/)) and one can allways improve on them or make something completely new

If Java and PHP are your only choices, well... How big is the project going to get?

Recently I had a look into [Magento](http://www.magentocommerce.com/), and I must say PHP is *not* the tool for such a big project.
Java *compiles*, PHP *doesn't*. Don't get *too* enterprisy with PHP, or secure a good hosting.

However, one can get resonabley "enterprisy" with PHP, since PHP has well-developed OOP infrastructure, and there are some good frameworks that are built upon that.
And PHP is more "at home" on the web, but I never did any Java for web, so I may be wrong.

Let me repeat once again - [Django](http://www.djangoproject.com/) :)

Answer (score 1):

Please check this [Comparison of Programming Languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_programming_languages), in order to develop your own conclusions according to the needs of your project.

Comment: That is not a helpful document to get informed to make a decision.  Just a list of languages.